# Does MSMQ need to be installed on your local machine in order to use remote queues?

Tags: msmq

When you send messages to remote queue, a temporary outgoing queue is created on your own machine. Does this mean that if MSMQ is not installed on your own machine, you can't use remote queues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. if MSMQ is not installed on your own machine, you can't use remote queues.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. MSMQ is a transport protocol. Imagine having two machines but only one has TCP/IP installed. Same scenario.